# Excel - using defined name in a SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel-formula, names, excel-indirect

I am trying to evaluate a simple SUMPRODUCT between 2 rows. But one of the row contains an array of Defined Names (each one being linked to a single numeric value).
I have used the INDIRECT function to recall the numbers related to the Defined Names but I understand that INDIRECT is not managing well this array and thus the SUMPRODUCT return an error.
`=SUMPRODUCT (A1:C1 , INDIRECT (A2:C2))`
where A2:C2 contains respectively {EUR,GBP,USD} names defined as exchange rate of the day (single numeric value in name manager)

Answer (score 0):

The INDIRECT function takes as an argument a reference, or a named range defined as a reference; not a range of names (named ranges).
I believe you have 2 alternatives though:
1) Give the INDIRECT the real reference to your values (as a range), or
2) Create one named range to reference all your values and give it as an argument to the INDIRECT.
HTH,
Matan